# Can't load layout in service controller

Tags: magento2, layout, layout-update

I'm using the **webapi** with a service controller to load some product attributes and replace them on the product detail page.

Now I need a whole block also. 
So far, I didn't face any problem. I fetched **Result LayoutFactory** and added a handle **"catalog_product_view"** and after that I just used

```
$resultLayout->getLayout()
        ->getBlock('my_product_attachments')
        ->getAttachments();
```

But then Magento told me that there are no blocks.

Isn't it possible to get the block content while I'm inside a service controller ?